In staging ground, hovering over a user's name should show rep
I often use the feature where if you hover your mouse over a user's name it will show you their reputation score.  This is particularly useful in assessing how much I want to trust the user's contribution or feedback.
But in Staging Ground, this feature seems to be missing.  To see a reviewer's rep from a comment in the Feedback and comments section I have to actually click their name and visit their profile.  I would prefer if hovering showed their rep.

This seems like is a "feature" of the nested comments.

This was suggested during the beta but marked [status-deferred].

Me too. I asked a similar question, but due to the comments and downvotes I thought it evidently wasn't a good idea; I ended up deleting the post.  But over time, I've actually missed having a similar feature.  :-) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430851/the-reviewers-rep-is-not-displayed


This is particularly useful in assessing how much I want to trust the user's contribution or feedback.

I think this is falling into the long-existing trap of using rep as a proxy for how much to trust someone's experience/alignment with site norms. Unfortunately, even help pages that way predate SG reinforce that. It can often coincide with a person having more site experience/alignment with site norms, but not fully, and it's frequently challenged how much and what kind of weight rep should hold in the system and in peoples' minds. Not that I can tell you what to believe.
At least for me, rep has little to do with understanding of what makes a good question. At least- not directly. A relatively stronger proxy would be the reviewer's reviewer stats (how "successful" are the questions that get published after they leave reviews? / how "successful" are the questions they publish from SG?). Even those are debatable as proxies. Alternative ideas that could be good for discussion are how much other reviewers in the closure queues agree with them. In any case, I challenge this idea of the value of seeing a reviewer's rep in SG to decide how much to trust the reviewer's feedback. I'm not totally against it. I don't think it's actively harmful. I just don't think it's a good solution for your use-case.
Also, I just... don't think it's particularly hard to tell if you should "trust" someone's feedback in SG. Actually, I just can't tell what this has to do with trust at all. Most SG feedback (at least the canned comments, which I find cover the majority of issues that SG is intended to deal with) are very straightforward. They either apply to the post, or they don't. If they don't apply, it should be easy to tell, and you should maybe flag the comment for removal as "no longer needed". If the feedback is applicable and in the scope of what SG is supposed to be for, trust doesn't even need to come into the picture. The feedback should be actioned.

Regarding flagging SG comments as NLN if they aren't applicable: Note that the OP often edits their post to fix these comments (as intended). In that case, flagging is just unnecessary effort.

@dan1st to be clear, I was talking about comments were not applicable at the time they were posted. assuming posts have fewer issues over time (which I know is not a great assumption, but it's one I made anyway), then it would never be applicable, and a mod might want to look to see if there's a pattern of bad reviewing.

"It can often coincide with a person having more site experience/alignment with site norms" - Yes, while not always, but in many cases the reputation reflects a person's knowledge of site norms. And this is why the reputation is shown (by hovering over a user name) e.g. in the comments to regular questions and answers. One of the important aspects of Staging Ground is to teach a new member for those norms (at least the norms of asking questions). I find illogical to not show a reputation specifically in that case.

@starball Yes I don't doubt you meaning that but IMO it isn't that clear.

@Tsyvarev I'd argue that askers shouldn't need to care about one reviewer being more experienced/having more rep than another/they shouldn't need to care about reviewer rep at all. On the other hand, reviewers should have some experience (there's also the 500 rep limit) on what a question should look like.

Yes, it would be great to add some nuance to the reputation system to have it reflect a more context-driven, merit-based metric.  But my proposal is just a tooltip to make existing information more easily accessible.  I'm not trying to be philosophical about how to use the information.  I don't want to misrepresent your position, but I think you should make it more explicitly clear whether or not you prefer to bury the reputation score (not make it readily accessible with a tooltip) because you don't think it is useful in that context.

@Wyck I think I make myself pretty clear: "I'm not totally against it. I don't think it's actively harmful. I just don't think it's a good solution for your use-case."
